# analog signal in sample and hold circuit

Tags: dsp

if  an analogue signal is sampled at a rate of 11.025 kHz and the acquisition time of the sampler is  10 micro sec .how much time is available for quantization and digitization?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a homework question with no attempt at a solution.

Answer (score 3):

The reciprocal of frequency is time. Taking the reciprocal of the sample rate and subtracting the S+H time will give you how much time you have to digitize the signal per sample.